# I have a pyspark dataframe where I have to join two columns orderby ascending and taking only top value out of it

Tags: sql, pyspark

'''
for EG:

My SPARK DATAFRAME  OR TABLE

```
       A       B
  |--------|----------|
  |    B   |     c    |
  |    K   |     G    |
  |    g   |     A    |
  | None   |   None   |
  | -------|----------|
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
       AB
  |--------|
  |    B   | 
  |    G   |
  |    A   |
  | None   | 
  |--------|
```

How to do Sorting the both as an array and taking the first value. (I'm VERY NEW)

THANKS IN ADVANCE

'''

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the characters directly

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object CompareCol {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = List(("B", "c"), ("K", "G"), ("g", "A"), (null, null)).toDF("A", "B")


    df
      .withColumn("arrayCol", array_min(array(col("A"), col("B"))))
      .show()
  }

}
```

Comment: It's a good answer but when I compare with null or none it is giving me null EG : c | null Then result is null which has to be c

Comment: Updated the condition for Null checks

Comment: If you don't mind can you please tell me how do we add if there are more than 2 columns,  I mean three or four... Can we do compare only or is there another way

Comment: added code for multiple columns. You eventually drove me to the better solution. @Hemanthsai